# git svn fetch & rebase broken after connection failure

Tags: git, git-svn

I lost my network connection during `git svn dcommit` when it was trying to rebase. I tried to `git svn rebase` again, but again lost my network connection.

Now, after sorting out my network connection problems, I am left with a situation in which `git svn rebase` and `git svn fetch` both do nothing.

I know that the SVN commit did indeed happen because a successful Jenkins build was triggered from SVN. But the SVN version of the commit doesn't show up in `git log trunk` after doing a `git svn fetch`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check if this isn't because of the local metadata stored in your git-svn repo, as described in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/dokipen/372883):

> The problem is, `git-svn` decided to store some metadata about what revisions were checked so it doesn't have to check them again based on the remote tracking branch name.
>   It's not going to check them again as long as that data exists.
>
> The solution is simple:

```
rm .git/svn/refs/remotes/mynewbranch -Rf && git svn fetch
```

In your case, try (on a copy of your local repo just for testing)

```
rm .git/svn/refs/remotes/trunk -Rf && git svn fetch
```